# How can I tell Emacs my git branch has changed?

Tags: git, emacs, version-control, dvcs

At the bottom of my Emacs 23 editor, I notice that Emacs is aware that I am working in a directory that is under version control, what that version control system is, and what branch I am currently on. Pretty cool! But say I am on the master branch, and from the command line I do a `git commit`, followed by a `git checkout <branch>`. Emacs still shows me being on the master branch. How do I refresh Emacs so that it reflects the branch I am currently on without closing down all my buffers and restarting it?

Comment: What happens if you just reload the file?

Comment: Is there an Emacs command to reload the file?

Comment: `revert-buffer` like giordano suggested

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `revert-buffer` but I suggest you to use [`magit-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Magit) to manage your git repos in Emacs.

For the record, I use to bind `revert-buffer` to <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```lisp
(global-set-key [f5] 'revert-buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Key-binding is perfect for now, but later looks like `magit-mode` is a more permanent solution.

Comment: @Houdini to avoid the annoying confirmation everytime you hit *F5*. Use `(global-set-key [f5] (lambda () (interactive) (revert-buffer nil t)))`

Answer (score 10):

You can revert buffer automatically by enable global-auto-revert-mode.
If you want to enable it, please add following code to your configuration file.

```
(global-auto-revert-mode 1)
(setq auto-revert-check-vc-info t)
```

Comment: If you open too many buffers, and your machine is hot, then you should set `auto-revert-interval' much bigger.

Answer (score 6):

To add to giordano's answer, if many files, which are under *git*, are opened. Then open *ibuffer* (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`ibuffer`) mark the buffers you want to reload using <kbd>m</kbd> and then <kbd>E</kbd> followed by `(revert-buffer nil t)`.

Comment: No need for the eval -- `V` runs `ibuffer-do-revert`. And of course there are many ways to mark buffers en-masse in ibuffer, so use `C-h m` to check out its features if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: In addition, if you're mixing ibuffer and version control, you probably want to check out [ibuffer-vc](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-vc) as well.

Comment: Great thanks phils. I am finally starting to try using my version control system and editor in conjunction with each other, as opposed to jumping back to the command line for `git` commands.